# Should Jacoco Agent be added to JVM where tests are executed, or on the JVM where the app server is running?

Tags: ant, selenium, sonarqube, agent, jacoco

I am instrumenting Selenium tests that run against an application in a JBoss server. Many documentations mention that the Jacoco agent should be added as a parameter to the JVM. However, they do not state whether they mean the JVM where the Selenium tests are running or the JVM where the JBoss app server is running. They are totally different machines. So, is the Jacoco Agent added to:

```
1. the app server JVM upon start
2. or the JVM where Selenium tests are run?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to use JaCoCo with Selenium tests, but obviously the agent should somehow be attached the JVM that runs the compiled sources of your application so that it can intrument your code at runtime (therefore, this is on server side).

Comment: Hmm ok that makes sense. It is also possible that Jacoco needs to be "attached" on the testing JVM side too (so it can link the test case being executed against a particular set of source code) but again, I haven't found any exact documentation on this (step-by-step).